# Problem saving many instances of manyToMany relationship Typeorm

Tags: typescript, postgresql, many-to-many, typeorm

### Description

Thank you very much in advance.
When using @joinTable specifying the name of the table and columns, the save method for multiple instances does not work by saving only the first one

I have a many-to-many relationship (N-> N), when users has where several users can have several types,I have the following tables:

**Table users**:

| Columns | types |
| --- | --- |
| id | uuidv4 |
| name | string |
| email | string |

**Table users_types**:

| Columns | types |
| --- | --- |
| id | uuidv4 |
| name | string |
| description | string |

**Table users_users_types**:

| Columns | types |
| --- | --- |
| id | uuidv4 |
| user_id | uuid |
| user_type_id | uuid |

**Models**:
**User**:

```
import {
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  DeleteDateColumn,
  Entity,
  JoinTable,
  ManyToMany,
  PrimaryColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn,
} from "typeorm";

import { TypeUser } from "@modules/accounts/infra/typeorm/entities/TypeUser";


@Entity("users")
class User {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id?: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  email: string;

  @ManyToMany((type) => TypeUser, (type_user) => type_user.users, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  @JoinTable({
    name: "users_types_users",
    joinColumns: [{ name: "user_id", referencedColumnName: "id" }],
    inverseJoinColumns: [{ name: "user_type_id", referencedColumnName: "id" }],
  })
  types?: TypeUser[];

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created_at?: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updated_at?: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deleted_at?: Date;

}

export { User };
```

TypeUser:

```
import {
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  DeleteDateColumn,
  Entity,
  JoinTable,
  ManyToMany,
  PrimaryColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn,
} from "typeorm";

import { User } from "./User";

@Entity("types_users")
class TypeUser {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id?: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  active: boolean;

  @ManyToMany((type) => User, (user) => user.types)
  users?: User[];

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created_at?: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updated_at?: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deleted_at?: Date;
}

export { TypeUser };
```

I'm assembling the seeds to test the insertion with the following code:

```
import { getConnection, MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from "typeorm";

import { TypeUser } from "@modules/accounts/infra/typeorm/entities/TypeUser";
import { User } from "@modules/accounts/infra/typeorm/entities/User";
import { UsersTypesFactory } from "@shared/infra/typeorm/factories";

export class CreateUsersTypes1620665114995 implements MigrationInterface {
  public async up(): Promise<void> {
    const users = (await getConnection("seed")
      .getRepository("users")
      .find()) as User[];

    const usersTypesFactory = new UsersTypesFactory();

    const types = usersTypesFactory.generate();

    await getConnection("seed").getRepository("types_users").save(types);

    const types_list = (await getConnection("seed")
      .getRepository("types_users")
      .find()) as TypeUser[];

    const types_users_list = Array.from({
      length: types_list.length,
    }).map((_, index) => types_list[index]) as TypeUser[];
    users[0].types = types_users_list;
    const relationshipUsersTypes = users[0];

    await getConnection("seed")
      .getRepository(User)
      .save(relationshipUsersTypes);
  }

  public async down(): Promise<void> {
    await getConnection("seed").getRepository("users_types_users").delete({});
    await getConnection("seed").getRepository("types_users").delete({});
  }
}
```

when executing the code the logs seem to be right:

```
query: START TRANSACTION
query: INSERT INTO "users_types_users"("user_id", "user_type_id") VALUES ($1, $2), ($3, $4), ($5, $6) -- PARAMETERS: ["8b90cacb-52bc-4635-bd2c-bc87d59b0d4d","9144899a-6380-4be6-8251-947b5bdccda9","8b90cacb-52bc-4635-bd2c-bc87d59b0d4d","7711c9a8-10c4-407d-a868-82234e85c614","8b90cacb-52bc-4635-bd2c-bc87d59b0d4d","581417e3-0790-4ea7-9bff-ca0f51bb16a4"]      
query: COMMIT
query: INSERT INTO "migrations"("timestamp", "name") VALUES ($1, $2) -- PARAMETERS: [1620665114995,"CreateUsersTypes1620665114995"]
logger this instance save
```

```
User {
  id: '8b90cacb-52bc-4635-bd2c-bc87d59b0d4d',
  name: 'Brice',
  last_name: 'Will',
  cpf: 'xfpfnxowprx',
  rg: '91r7aujxsl',
  email: 'Toney.Bailey@hotmail.com',
  password_hash: 'fe6eYzQXKp3kHyt',
  birth_date: 2020-07-17T04:46:14.816Z,
  created_at: 2021-05-12T05:43:22.064Z,
  updated_at: null,
  deleted_at: null,
  types: [
    TypeUser {
      id: '9144899a-6380-4be6-8251-947b5bdccda9',
      name: 'provider',
      active: true,
      created_at: 2021-05-12T05:43:22.291Z,
      updated_at: null,
      deleted_at: null
    },
    TypeUser {
      id: '7711c9a8-10c4-407d-a868-82234e85c614',
      name: 'client',
      active: true,
      created_at: 2021-05-12T05:43:22.291Z,
      updated_at: null,
      deleted_at: null
    },
    TypeUser {
      id: '581417e3-0790-4ea7-9bff-ca0f51bb16a4',
      name: 'admin',
      active: true,
      created_at: 2021-05-12T05:43:22.291Z,
      updated_at: null,
      deleted_at: null
    }
  ]
}
```

but in the database only the content of the first one was saved
content **users_types_users**

[image]
content **type_users**
[image]
content **users**
[image]

#### Expected Behavior

the expected result is that all available types are registered

#### Actual Behavior

only the first element of the type class instance is registered

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. create a database with tables
2. includes data in table

#### My Environment

| Dependency | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Operating System |  |
| Node.js version | v14.16.1 |
| Typescript version | v4.2.3 |
| TypeORM version | v0.2.32 |

- [x] `postgres`

I added this as a Bug but, I wanted to answer the question if someone has already gone through the same problem or managed to solve it?